# jQuery not working with jsp page

Tags: jquery, jsp, jquery-validate

This jsp page is not taking the jQuery to validate. Please check
The jsp page contains two form fields which needs to be validated. I think i am missing something.The text field should be validated to check for numbers and maximum of 4 numbers only.

```
    <html>

    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/site-demos.css">



    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="ChangePIN"  id="myform"  method="post" >
        <table width="100%" height="100%">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><%@include file="atmAdmin.jsp"%>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr height="100%">
                <td colspan="2" align="center">
                    <div style="">Enter old and new PIN</div>
                    <table style="font-family: verdana font-size : 38px" align="center">

                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td font-size="28px">Enter Old PIN No.</td>
                            <td><input type="name" id="oldPin" name="oldPin">
                            </td><td><span id="m1" ></span>
                                </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <br>
                            <td></td>

                        </tr>
                        <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td font-size="28px">Enter New Pin</td>
                            <td><input type="name" id="newPin" name="newPin" >
                            </td><td><span id="m2" ></span>
                                </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <br>
                            <td></td>
                            <td align="center"><input type="submit" value="submit" >
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </form>

                    </table></td>
            </tr>
            <tr width="22px" valign="bottom">
                <td colspan="2"><%@include file="atmFoot.jsp"%>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
                        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
                        <script src="http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/jquery.validate.js"></script>
                        <script src="http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/additional-methods.js"></script>
                        <script>
                        //just for the demos, avoids form submit
$(document).ready(function(){
                        jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
                        debug: true,
                        success: "valid"
                        });
                        $( "#myform" ).validate({
                        rules: {
                        oldPin: {
                        required: true,
                        digits: true,
                        maxLength: 4
                        },
                        newPin: {
                        required: true,
                        digits: true,
                        maxLength: 4
                        }
                        }
                        });
});
                        </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Please help me out as I am a newbie.

Comment: If you have a program with JavaScript not working, then don't show us server side code. Show us the client side code you are generating.

Comment: Also, when somebody provides an answer pointing out the problems in your code, don't edit your question to remove these errors.  You completely disconnected all the previous answers so they're no longer relevant.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap code inside document.ready.

```
$(function(){
   // validation code
});
```

And you also forgot to define ID `myform` for the `FORM`.

Define `form` as below.

```
<form action="ChangePIN"  id="myform"  method="post">
```

and you do not need to call function `onClick`

Comment: No, the JavaScript appears *after* the elements that it is trying to modify. There is no need to delay it.

Comment: @Quentin Yeah i know i was just editing the answer, but you were too quick to judge me...+1 for your comment.

Comment: Your attempts to edit your answer appear to have failed. Your answer is still claiming that document.ready will help.

Comment: @ASIF remove onlclick attribut of form because `$('#myform').validate()` will do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

The selector `#myform` doesn't match any element you have in the document. The only form you have doesn't have an id at all.

Also, your HTML has numerous validity errors, the most significant of which is that a form cannot be a child element of a table or a parent element of a table row. Error recovery mechanisms in browsers will often move the form so it appears after the table (but will leave the inputs behind). Use [a validator](http://validator.w3.org).

Your form has an `onclick` attribute (which rarely makes sense, usually you would want `onsubmit`, and you would bind event handlers with JS and not HTML) which calls a `Val` function you have no defined.

Answer (score 0):

Your rules are invalid...

```
maxLength: 4
```

Should be...

```
maxlength: 4
```

Please note that JavaScript is case-sensitive.

---

You also have terribly malformed HTML.  Only specific elements like `<td>` are allowed to be direct descendants of the `<table>` tag.

```
<form>
    <table>
        ....
        <table>
             ....
        </form>  <!-- you can't close form here! -->
    </table>
    ....
</table>
```

Should be...

```
<form>
    <table>
        ....
            <table>
                ....
            </table>
        ....
    </table>
</form>
```

You still have invalid HTML, some stray `td` or `tr` tags I don't care to track down.  At least the validation is working now...

**Working DEMO**:  http://jsfiddle.net/eM2TK/

I suggest that you put your code through the [W3C HTML Online Validator Tool](http://validator.w3.org/) and fix all errors.